# Find similar strings/fields in different files

Tags: bash

Let's say we have the following files.
file1.csv:

```
    file_name,cognitive_complexity,working_memory
    001_Two_Sum.java,3,0
    002_Add_Two_Numbers.java,11,0
    012_Integer_to_Roman.java,3,0
```

file2.csv:

```
file_name,method_name,cognitive_complexity,size,working_memory
001_Two_Sum,twoSum,5,82,7
002_Add_Two_Numbers,addTwoNumbers,7,86,8
003_Longest_Substring_Without_Repeating_Characters,lengthOfLongestSubstring,4,77,7
```

Desired results:

```
file_name,java_cognitive_complexity,python_cognitive_complexity
001_Two_Sum,3,5
002_Add_Two_Numbers,11,7
```

Notice that there are file names that have the same names but with different extensions. We want to get the similar file names without the extension with the corresponding cognitive complexity field and output in a different file. All filenames in `file1.csv` have the extension `.java` and filenames in `file2.csv` have the extension `.py`.
I know the `grep -ow -F -f file1.txt file2.txt` command can be used to get matching strings in two different files but the problem is that I can't manipulate it to ignore the file extensions. Also, the below script can be used to iterate over the lines in CSV files and get the fields one is interested in. Is there a way to combine the two to achieve the desired results?

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3
    do
        echo "$col1, $col2"
    done < file1.csv
```

Comment: Where did the string `python` in `python_cognitive_complexity` come from?

Comment: do you understand how that `while/read` loop works? the `while/read` loop is reading 4 columns from a file named `myfile.csv` but your files (`file1.csv`, `file2.csv`) have 3 and 5 columns, respectively; the `while/read` loop you've provided doesn't appear to have anything to do with your situation; please update the question with your coding attempt at parsing, matching and generating the desired output

Comment: This is yet another a variant of the most frequently asked question on this forum - search the archives for an awk script that starts with `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} ...` or similar as a starting point for how to solve your problem.

Comment: will all filenames in `file1.csv` have an extension of `.java`? if not, please update the sample inputs to show different extensions; also, explain how to process the non-`.java` entries?

Comment: Yes all filenames in `file1.csv` have the extension `.java` and `file2.csv` have `.py`

Comment: `python_cognitive_complexity` is the `cognitive_complexity` in `file2.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier in awk:

```
awk  '
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS=","
    print "file_name","java_cognitive_complexity","python_cognitive_complexity"
}
FNR==1{next}
FNR==NR{sub(/\.java$/,"",$1); f1[$1]=$2; next}
$1 in f1{print $1, f1[$1],$3}
' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Or in Ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
f1={}
CSV.read(ARGV[0], headers: true).each{|row|
    f1[row["file_name"].sub(/\.java$/,"")]=row["cognitive_complexity"]
}

puts CSV.generate(headers:true){|csv|
    csv<<["file_name","java_cognitive_complexity","python_cognitive_complexity"]
    
    f2=CSV.read(ARGV[1], headers: true).each{|row|
        if f1.has_key?(row["file_name"])
            csv<<[row["file_name"], f1[row["file_name"]], row["cognitive_complexity"] ]
        end
    }
}' file1.csv file2.csv
```

(The Ruby is better if you have a true CSV file with potentially quoted fields...)

If you *really really really* want Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A f1 
while IFS=',' read -ra la; do
    f1["${la[0]%.java}"]="${la[1]}"
done < <(tail -n +2 file1.csv)    

echo "file_name,java_cognitive_complexity,python_cognitive_complexity"
while IFS=',' read -ra la; do
    key="${la[0]}"
    [[  -v "f1[$key]" ]] && printf "%s,%s,%s\n" "$key" "${f1[$key]}" "${la[2]}"
done < <(tail -n +2 file2.csv)
```

Any prints:

```
file_name,java_cognitive_complexity,python_cognitive_complexity
001_Two_Sum,3,5
002_Add_Two_Numbers,11,7
```